# Commands to use after converting from expo to react-native-cli

Tags: android-studio, react-native, expo

What other command should I run alongside react-native start after converting a project built using expo to react-native-cli?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `command` from `Expo`, even if you run an `eject` from the `Expo`. You do not need to use the `React-native` command.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you need? If you are asking from command to run the app on device then you should run

`react-native run-android//or ios`

Just keep in mind you gotta have both metro bundler and emulator running. You can read more [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started)

Comment: I needed what you've just gave (Which only works iff I have ejected the project)